# How to automate updating a ClearCase view using rcleartool?

Tags: batch-file, cleartool, clearcase-remote-client

I want to do automation of the process of taking latest code from ClearCase.
I am able to get latest using `rcleartool` in cmd successfully.

Now, I need to automate this cmd script as well.
Can someone please suggest me how should I go about it?
Should I create a `.bat` file?

Also, does `rcleartool` command return some value (0 or 1) (apart from the "done loading" message, so that my program can check whether or not the update process was successful?

Answer (score 1):

[`rcleartool update`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm) can be put in a script (like a `.bat` one, as long as the `%PATH%` is correct) as is:

```
cd /d C:\path\to\snapshot\view
rcleartool update
```

The [cleartool man page](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/cleartool.htm) mentions (and it *should* be the same for `rcleartool`)

> The exit status from single-command mode depends on whether the command succeeded (zero exit status) or generated an error message (nonzero exit status).